# Language Server Provider - Get Line Break Type

Tags: node.js, line-breaks, language-server-protocol

I'm trying to get the line break type (CRLF or LF) of the client document, but can't find any reference to it in the docs. I need something like this in the server.ts file:

```
function validateTextDocument(textDocument) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        if (textDocument.lineBreak === "\n") {
            // ...
        }
    })
}
```

This is the last piece of information I need to finish my extension, can you please shed a light on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I missed the obvious, the solution has nothing to do with LSP, you can find it here: [Detecting type of line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820267/detecting-type-of-line-breaks)

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to explicitly state the answer (not just a link, that eventually goes dead) and then accept it.